# Calculate Distinct Sums in PowerPivot

Tags: powerpivot

I have a transaction history that follows the below format, and I need to sum up the unique amounts per transaction.

**Sample Data:**

```
Transaction ID  Transaction Date    Activity Date   Amount
1001            10/30/2014          11/5/2014       $50.00 
1001            10/30/2014          11/7/2014       $50.00 
1002            11/2/2014           11/14/2014      $100.00 
1002            11/2/2014           11/17/2014      $100.00
```

I tried two approaches, based on the way the data is formatted, either trying to filter for unique transaction ids:

=CALUCLATE(SUM(TRANSACTION HISTORY[AMOUNT]),DISTINCT(TRANSACTION HISTORY[TRANSACTION ID]))

Or to sum up based on the earliest activity date:

=CALUCLATE(SUM(TRANSACTION HISTORY[AMOUNT]),EARLIEST(TRANSACTION HISTORY[ACTIVITY DATE]))

Both formulas result in errors though.  Anyone have an a different approach for how this could be summed?  The answer I'm trying to get is Sum of Unique Amount = $150.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to approach this is probably with one of the X functions which iterate over the data specified performing the calculation under that context and then summarising the results. Try this:

```
=SUMX(
      VALUES(transaction_history[Transaction_ID]), 
      AVERAGE(transaction_history[Amount])
      )
```